# Error when trying to inherit from another subclass?

Tags: java

```
public class Vehicle {

  private double speed;
  private int wheels;

  public Vehicle() {

  }

  public Vehicle(double speed, int wheels) {
    this.speed = speed;
    this.wheels = wheels;
  }

}


public class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {

  private double engineSize;

  public Motorcycle(double speed, double engine) {
    super(speed, 2);
    this.engineSize = engine;
  }

}


public class Moped extends Motorcycle {


}
```

Since Mope extends Motorcycle why is it telling me Moped needs to make a constructor? I want Moped to work without having any constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Motorcycle` doesn't have a *default constructor*, you can't use it in `Moped` - but you could add an empty constructor for `Moped` - like,

```
public class Moped extends Motorcycle {
    public Moped() {
        super(70, 50); //<-- or whatever values you want 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a class does not have a no-args constructor, then every subclass has to call one of it's explicitly defined constructors via super(). This is an example of Java being a verbose language; it will not assume that it can inherit a constructor.